# Disabling the X-Redirect-By response header

Tags: redirect, headers, http

Is there a clean way to not have WordPress send the `X-Redirect-By` response header when redirects happen? I'd like to disable it in order not to expose information about our software stack. Something I can hook into `functions.php` perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line added to functions.php (ideally in a child theme, or a plugin) will remove it:

```
add_filter( 'x_redirect_by', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: That totally works! Thanks Jacob.